# Не работает Image view

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Не работает Image view. Перетаскиваю его на активити, и выбираю изображение, в формате png. Но, когда оно появляется, оно пустое. Что не так?
Изображение в папке drawable.

Comment: Выложите код, что бы мы понимали о чем идет речь